# ImportError: cannot import name 'FormatControl' when trying to use pip

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, conda

I recently removed a python package (pymc3) and I think I probably messed it up and removed more than just that, because now I can't install anything with pip. When I try to use pip (or pip3) I get the following traceback and error message:

```
 my_name:~ my_name$ pip3 install pymc3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda3/bin/pip3", line 6, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    from pip._internal import cmdoptions
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_internal/cmdoptions.py", line 16, in <module>
    from pip._internal.index import (
ImportError: cannot import name 'FormatControl'
```

Can anyone help me reconfigure my environment to get this working again? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have anaconda installed. Have you tried reinstalling pip3 and Python using:

```
conda install python pip3
```

(From conda's website: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-pkgs.html and https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-python.html)

I recommend creating environments using conda so that you can break them, delete them and reinstall them without having to worry about not having a working environment anymore.

Comment: Thanks - i ended up deleting anaconda entirely and reinstalling it which worked - your solution would probably have been simpler!

Answer (score 2):

Try and downgrade your pip version to `9.0.3` in your conda environment. There is something broken with more updated versions of pip when trying to access the main from the environment pip from what I could figure out